# Why is there new column error when there is no any named column mentioned in query?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

Here is my sql query :

```
INSERT INTO `payment` (`payment_type`, `entry_id`, `transaction_amount`, `description`) 
VALUES ('1', '156', '12500.00', 'fsdf')
```

While executing this query in phpmyadmin, I am getting following error

https://nimb.ws/4YEVIk[image]

While this is no sales_id in table structure.

Here is my table structure.

https://nimb.ws/9bBtVi[image]

Can any one help me in this?

Answer (score 2):

Later on, I found that As I was working on the existing database and customize the full system, there was some trigger exist on that 'payment' table and error was coming due to trigger.

So `sales_id` in error was coming due to existing trigger in database.

I am posting this as the answer so it may help someone to identify the error in such case.

Comment: You can choose to accept this answer. My preference would be simply to delete the question.

Comment: I am not able to delete the question. and other hand i am able to accept the answer after 2 days as per stackoverflow rules.

Comment: I guess you need more rep. Here's some ;-)